# How to log GPU utilisation in python

Tags: python, gpu

I have been using a library called GPUtil to try and log the utilisation percentage value of my GPU in an array.

The command i have used outputs too many pieces of data to be added to my array. I only want the percentage utilisation of the core. The memory utilisation doesn't concern me.

The two arrays are being used for a graph in PyQtgraph

The function I have written looks like this:

```
import GPUtil
import time
time_x = []
gpu_y = []

def gpu_util_timer(self):
    for n in range(10):
        Graph_Util.gpu_y.append(GPUtil.showUtilization())
        Graph_Util.time_x.append(n)
        time.sleep(1)
    print('gpu done')
```

I have since taken the advice below and implmented it as such:

```
def N_gpu_util_timer(self):
    for n in range(10):
        GPUs = GPUtil.getGPUs()
        gpu_load = GPUs[0].load
        Graph.gpu_y.append(gpu_load)
        time.sleep(1)
    print(Graph.gpu_y)
    print('N gpu done')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the documentation

https://github.com/anderskm/gputil#usage

Use getGPUs and query the GPU class's load member

```
GPUs = GPUtil.getGPUs()
load = GPUs[0].load
```